# Using Accessorizer it doesn't generate any dealloc code for NSString properties

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, xcode4, accessorizer

I'm using the Accessorizer code helper for xCode.  I seem to have it configured correctly and it is generating property statements and synthesize statements fine.

It is not generating the release statements however when I choose the dealloc action.

If I choose dealloc against an NSTimer, it does generate the [myTimer invalidate] statement, but not the release statements, so it seems to be triggering the dealloc action, but the action isn't configured properly? and so no release code generated.

Has anyone come across an issue like this using accessorizer?

Comment: Sounds reasonable if you're working in a project with ARC enabled, since it's a problem I assume you're not?

Comment: yeah I agree the behaviour from accessorizer is perfectly reasonable . Would be nice if the Xcode IDE allowed us to create our own macro's or equivalent so we didn't need accessorizer and so we could integrate better into the Xcode IDE (e.g. whether ARC is on or not could be a parameter accessible from our macro).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazing how you find an answer just after asking a question.

For anyone else that has this issue, turn off ARC Aware in the Accessor Style TAB of the Accessorizer application.  (yes seems bleedingly obvious in hindsight, was stupidly thinking it might be aware of the xcode project settings and ARC isn't on for this project, but its really just a 'dumb' editing tool that operates only on the input text i.e. not integrated to xCode).

The things we have to go through to do something that anyone who codes objective C for more than half an hour would have made the first feature of a new IDE. (automatic generation of property/synthesize etc.)

Comment: Not associated etc, but if you're after more "integrated IDE" assistance, take a look at AppCode (https://www.jetbrains.com/objc/) Not an AppCode customer myself, but I could never live without my ReSharper :)

Comment: Thanks - looks very interesting - bit of a big step to switch to it, but I suppose it could also be used alongside xCode. If I get time I'll give it a whirl.